# Calling external JS function from inline JS in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, realex-payments-api

I am implementing a payment gateway and am trying to get the following JS to run on my JSF page which should in turn bringg up a light box

```
<p:commandButton id="testBtn" value="test btn" onclick="$(document).ready(function ()  {

                    RealexHpp().setHppUrl('https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay');
                    RealexHpp().init('testBtn', 'http://www.google.com', getJSON(document.getElementById('realF:hidden2').value));

            });"/>
```

The problem the RealexHpp() is contained in a separate .js file in my resources/js directory and when I try to run the above code I get an error that RealexHpp is not defined.

How can I get around this.  BTW the api docs are here (https://developer.realexpayments.com/#!/hosted-payments/auth/java/html_js)

Comment: You haven't stated whether you have included your .js file. eg. <script src="myscripts.js"></script>

Comment: I have these two in the head`<h:outputScript library="js" name="rxp-js.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-3.1.1.min.js" target="head" />`

Comment: Hello,

The sample code provided on the Developer Hub is the following: `RealexHpp.setHppUrl("https://pay.realexpayments.com/pay"); RealexHpp.init("payButtonId", "responseUrl", jsonFromServerSdk);`
Whereas you have RealexHpp().setHppURL.